# Combining two tuples based on id in OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a tuple called blockType

```
tuple blockType {
    key string id;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
 };
{blockType} PitBlocksType =…; \\read from excel
```

A snapshot of the data is like below

```
P1  1   1   2
P2  1   1   3
P3  1   1   4
P4  1   1   5
P5  1   1   6
P6  1   1   7
P7  1   1   8
P8  1   1   9
P9  1   1   10
P10 1   1   11
```

And another tuple

```
tuple Path {
int id;
string source;
string dest;
{string} pitblockSet;
{string} roadPoints; // not used
{string} dumpblockSet;
{string} others;
float dist;
};
```

{Path} Pbd is read from excel and the data looks as below:

```
PathId  Source  Destination pitBlockSet Road    DumpBlockSet         Others Distance
1       P1      D1         P1           R8       D45 D42 D39 D14 D1         581.3956
2       P1      D1         P1           R8       D40 D14 D1                 587.1185
3       P1      D1         P1           R8       D43 D16 D2 D1              588.7774
4       P2      D1         P2 P44       R8       D45 D42 D39 D14 D1         539.7307
```

In this case my particular interest is on pitBlockSet which just contains the id of the blockType, it can have one or more Ids like P1 P23 etc . I need to create a set which is of type {blockType}, and has the ids from pitBlockSet of Path and the rest of it from pitBlocksType. So it is an union of Path.pitBlockSet and of PitBlocksType.

I tried the following options :

```
{blockType} PitBlocksInPath[p in Pbd] = union(b in p.pitblockSet) PitBlocksType [<b>];
```

The errors I get is :

```
Not an array type
```

Is this a syntax error or it should not be union

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the problem is that `PitBlocksType` is not an array. It is a set. You can turn this into an array, to fix the error. If that is not an option then instead of `PitBlocksType[<b>]` you can write something like `{b2 | b2 in PitBlockType : b2.id == n}`, i.e., explicity create the singleton set of blocks that have id `b`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, did you mean : {blockType} PitBlocksInPathD[p in Pbd] = union(b in p.pitblockSet) {b2 | b2 in PitBlocksType : b2.id == b};      I have used it and it has solved the issue for now

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.